# Не парсится lurkmore.to

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, requests

Хотел парсить сайт https://lurkmore.to, однако, ни использование юзер агента, ни прокси не помогают, прилетает ошибка ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None), использую python 3.7 и requests, на других ресурсах с таким не сталкивался, в гугле ничего конкретно по этому сайту не нашел, задумка вообще в получении ссылки на случайную статью и дальнейшая работа с ней.
Исходный код (без прокси):

```
import requests

link = 'https://lurkmore.to/Служебная:Random'
header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 YaBrowser/19.7.0.1635 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'
}


def get_random_article(url_):
    sesion = requests.Session()
    r = sesion.get(url_, headers=header)
    return r.url


def main():
    print(get_random_article(link))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Ошибка целиком:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\PyCharm\venv_PyCharm\daily_articles\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "D:\python\PyCharm\venv_PyCharm\daily_articles\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 344, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "D:\python\PyCharm\venv_PyCharm\daily_articles\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 843, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "D:\python\PyCharm\venv_PyCharm\daily_articles\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 370, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "D:\python\PyCharm\venv_PyCharm\daily_articles\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 355, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "D:\Программы\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "D:\Программы\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 850, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "D:\Программы\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\PyCharm\venv_PyCharm\daily_articles\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "D:\python\PyCharm\venv_PyCharm\daily_articles\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "D:\python\PyCharm\venv_PyCharm\daily_articles\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 368, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "D:\python\PyCharm\venv_PyCharm\daily_articles\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "D:\python\PyCharm\venv_PyCharm\daily_articles\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "D:\python\PyCharm\venv_PyCharm\daily_articles\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 344, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "D:\python\PyCharm\venv_PyCharm\daily_articles\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 843, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "D:\python\PyCharm\venv_PyCharm\daily_articles\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 370, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "D:\python\PyCharm\venv_PyCharm\daily_articles\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 355, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "D:\Программы\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "D:\Программы\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 850, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "D:\Программы\Python\lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/python/PyCharm/daily_articles/daily_articles.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:/python/PyCharm/daily_articles/daily_articles.py", line 16, in main
    print(get_random_article(link))
  File "D:/python/PyCharm/daily_articles/daily_articles.py", line 11, in get_random_article
    r = sesion.get(url_, headers=header)
  File "D:\python\PyCharm\venv_PyCharm\daily_articles\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "D:\python\PyCharm\venv_PyCharm\daily_articles\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "D:\python\PyCharm\venv_PyCharm\daily_articles\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "D:\python\PyCharm\venv_PyCharm\daily_articles\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))
```

Comment: Он заблокирован на территории РФ.

Comment: Как, простите, тогда я на него захожу? Он открывается у меня в браузере, но не парсится через питон

Comment: Может быть у вас в бразуере установлено какое-либо расширение, позволяющее обходить блокировки? Типа Hola или AnonymoX.

Comment: Это намек на использование НЕ российских прокси? Просто вроде бы ничего не установлено

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev при блокировках соединение обычно не устанавливается вообще, а тут разрывается уже существующее, так что вряд ли

Comment: @andreymal мой провайдер именно разрывает соединения по https на заблокированные адреса.

Comment: @danilsokolov а какой браузер?

Comment: @andreymal Яндекс Браузер

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev с него сняли блокировку в РФ, насколько я помню.

Comment: @AlexKrass [нет](https://minjust.ru/ru/extremist-materials?field_extremist_content_value=lurk).

Answer (score 0):

Я решил свою проблему, использование прокси все-таки помогает, перебрал несколько штук и получил результат, однако с российскими срабатывает через раз, видимо, блокировка самого сайта в рф действительно сказывается, всем спасибо!